# ValueError: too many values to unpack for sorted dictionary

Tags: python

I got the exception "ValueError: too many values to unpack", what is the problem with following codes?

```
for key, item in sorted(resDic):
    outFiles.write('%s %s\n' % (key, item))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sorted(resDic)` only returns the keys. To return both the keys and the values, write `sorted(resDic.items())`:

```
for key, item in sorted(resDic.items()):
    outFiles.write('%s %s\n' % (key, item))
```

Comment: Could also go for: `outFiles.writelines('{} {}\n'.format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(resDict.items()))`

Comment: @JonClements This is cool, the {} is it a placeholder like %s, I can't find a documentation for this

Comment: @william007: and [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)